# SDL2 equivalent of SDLK_FIRST and SDLK_LAST?

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2

I am converting some code from SDL 1 to SDL 2 and I ran into an issue.

```
if (ksym > SDLK_FIRST && ksym < SDLK_LAST) {
  *retval = ksym;
  return TRUE;
}
```

I could hard-code the values I found on this [table (SDL Scancode Lookup Table)](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDLScancodeLookup), but that does not sit well with me.

Is there a more idiomatic way to check this?

Comment: `SDLK_FIRST` -> `0`, `SDLK_LAST` -> `SDL_NUM_SCANCODES`

Comment: [This](https://wiki.libsdl.org/MigrationGuide) could be helpful to you, particularly under the "Input" section.

Comment: Vunderbar. Thank you both.